# JAX-RS in Dropwizard: Handling async call with immediate response

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I have a Resource `Class`, with a `@ManagedAsync` method Class which looks like this:

```
@Path("my-resource")
public class MyResource extends BaseResource{

    private DatumDAO datumDAO;

    public MyResource(DatumDAO datumDAO){
        this.datumDAO = datumDAO;
    }

    public void cleanDatum(Datum datum){
       //time taking operations
    }

    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    @Path("/cleanup/{from}/{till}/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @UnitOfWork
    public void cleanupDirtyData(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @PathParam("from") DateTimeParam from,
            @PathParam("till") DateTimeParam till) throws IOException{

        logger.debug("will try to cleanup dirty data in range: " + from + " " +  till);
        List<Datum> data = datumDAO.getALlDirtyDatumInRange(from.get().toDate(), till.get().toDate());
        Map<Long,String> cleanupMap = new HashMap<Long,String>();
        for(Datum datum: data){
            cleanDatum(datum);
            cleanupMap.put(datum.getId(), "cleaned");
        }
        // this response need to be sent [can be ignored]       
        asyncResponse.resume(Response.status(HttpStatus.OK_200).entity(cleanupMap).build());

    }

}
```

Since the call to `cleanupDirtyData` can take a while, I don't want clients to wait for it completely, I understand that execution work is offloaded to a different worker thread.

**What I am trying to achieve is to give an immediate response to the client and keep doing execution of the function `cleanupDirtyData` asynchronously.**

So tried the following thing:

Putting a forceful timeout, and giving a premature response to the client, but that doesn't seem to be the ideal way and it stops the execution.

that would look something like this:

```
@Path("my-resource")
public class MyResource extends BaseResource{

    private DatumDAO datumDAO;

    public MyResource(DatumDAO datumDAO){
        this.datumDAO = datumDAO;
    }

    public void cleanDatum(Datum datum){
       //time taking operations
    }

    @GET
    @ManagedAsync
    @Path("/cleanup/{from}/{till}/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @UnitOfWork
    public void cleanupDirtyData(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse, @PathParam("from") DateTimeParam from,
            @PathParam("till") DateTimeParam till) throws IOException{

        // Register handler and set timeout
        asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(new TimeoutHandler() {
            public void handleTimeout(AsyncResponse ar) {
                asyncResponse.resume(Response.status(SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE).entity(
                    "Operation timed out -- please try again").build());                    
                }
        });
        ar.setTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);      

        logger.debug("will try to cleanup dirty data in range: " + from + " " +  till);
        List<Datum> data = datumDAO.getALlDirtyDatumInRange(from.get().toDate(), till.get().toDate());
        Map<Long,String> cleanupMap = new HashMap<Long,String>();
        for(Datum datum: data){
            cleanDatum(datum);
            cleanupMap.put(datum.getId(), "cleaned");
        }
       // this response need to be sent [can be ignored]              
        asyncResponse.resume(Response.status(HttpStatus.OK_200).entity(cleanupMap).build());

    }

}
```

Comment: _"Since the call to cleanupDirtyData can take a while, I don't want clients to wait for it completely"_ - You wanna know why that doesn't make sense? Because in your code you are are returning a response body to the client. If that response body is part of the "long running execution", how do you expect to return the response to the client when the execution to get the body is not done? If I am wrong, what exactly is the long running task in your code?

Comment: @peeskillet it was a placeholder code, I need not return any response after the job is done. The long running tasks involve lots of Disks I/Os which can take up to 15mins.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *JAX-RS Asynchronous Server API* is all about how the **container** will manage the request. But it will still hold the request and won't affect the client experience.

Quoting the Jersey documentation about the [Asynchronous Server API](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html):

> Note that the use of server-side asynchronous processing model will
>   not improve the request processing time perceived by the client. It
>   will however increase the throughput of the server, by releasing the
>   initial request processing thread back to the I/O container while the
>   request may still be waiting in a queue for processing or the
>   processing may still be running on another dedicated thread. The
>   released I/O container thread can be used to accept and process new
>   incoming request connections.

If you want to give the client an immediate response, you may be looking for something like:

```java
@Singleton
@Path("expensive-task")
public class ExpensiveTaskResource {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    private Future<String> futureResult;

    @PostConstruct
    public void onCreate() {
        this.executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }

    @POST
    public Response startTask() {
        futureResult = executor.submit(new ExpensiveTask());
        return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).build();
    }

    @GET
    public Response getResult() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        if (futureResult != null && futureResult.isDone()) {
            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(futureResult.get()).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("Try later").build();
        }
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.executor.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

```java
public class ExpensiveTask implements Callable<String> {

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "Task completed";
    }
}
```

In a servlet container, you can use an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to run your expensive task. In a Java EE container, you should consider a [`ManagedExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html).